# Hey, Im new in coding and wanted to make that when the bullet touches the player, it would recive damage

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So basically I want so that the enemy, which is shooting the player, to deal some damage.
I just don't know how to combine the two to make it work. I'll be thankful for your help.
..............................................................................................................................................
Here are my Heath and bullet scripts:

Health:

```
public class Health : MonoBehaviour
{
public Image healthBar;
public float healthAmount = 100;
public GameObject bullet;

private void Update()
{
    if (healthAmount <= 0)
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        TakeDamage(20);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T))
    {
        Healing(10);
    }
    if (bullet.)
}

public void TakeDamage(float Damage)
{
    healthAmount -= Damage;
    healthBar.fillAmount = healthAmount / 100;
}

public void Healing(float healPoints)
{
    healthAmount += healPoints;
    healthAmount = Mathf.Clamp(healthAmount, 0, 100);

    healthBar.fillAmount = healthAmount / 100;
}

}
```

Bullet:

```
public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour {

float moveSpeed = 25f;
public GameObject effect;
public GameObject player;


[SerializeField] private float attackDamage = 1f;

Rigidbody2D rb;

Player target;
Vector2 moveDirection;

// Use this for initialization
void Start() {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    target = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Player>();
    moveDirection = (target.transform.position - transform.position).normalized * moveSpeed;
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveDirection.x, moveDirection.y);
    Destroy(gameObject, 1f);
}
void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col)
{
    if(col.gameObject.tag.Equals("Player"))
    {
        Instantiate(effect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is obviously in `c#`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have the Health script attached to the player game object. The easiest way that you can add damage to the player would be to get a reference to the Health script you have attached to the player and use your TakeDamage function. You can do this in the OnCollisionEnter2D function attached to the bullet as follows:

```
playerhealth = col.GetComponent<Health>();
playerhealth.TakeDamage(5);
```

The end result should look something like this:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col)
{
    if(col.gameObject.tag.Equals("Player"))
    {
        Instantiate(effect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        playerhealth = col.GetComponent<Health>();
        playerhealth.TakeDamage(5);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: You wouldn't even need to check for the tag .. you can use `if(col.gameObject.TryGetComponent<Health>(out var health){ ...}` this way you can later on deal damage not only to the player but also to other objects with a `Health` component attached ;)

Comment: @derHugo I agree that is a good way to do it if you want to be able to have multiple objects with a Health script.

Answer (score 1):

In the Bullet script, get the Health Script from the player and call the function:

```
if(col.gameObject.tag.Equals("Player"))
{
    if (col.transform.TryGetComponent<Health>(out Health health))
    {
        health.TakeDamage(50); // deal damage to player
    }
    Instantiate(effect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

But I have to add some Notes that I think beginners should know:

Physics in Unity is always updating in FixedUpdate ~60 times per second, independent of the framerate. You could change the physics timestep, but it's fine for most things. However if you have really fast bullets, they may pass though the player, because in one frame the bullet ist "in front of", and in the next frame "behind" the player. So you should look into raycasts to check for the next pixels in front of the bullet (depending on velocity etc.)

Also, I use "tryGetComponent<>" which is recommended, because if you use "getComponent<>" and hit an object that doesn't have a "health" component attached, you get an error. So this is the safe way to do it.

Comment: This approach with `TryGetComponent` has another huge advantage: You can skip the tag check and later on deal damage to **any** object with a `Health` component attached .. not only the player necessarily